# Only prepend one time below a width and one time above a width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to prepend a header tag to my webpage when the browser size is below 768px and remove it when it is above 768px no matter how many times I switch between the two sizes. I created the code below and it works fine if I use the sizing window but if I manually resize it then it constantly fires, causing multiple header tags.

What I would like for it to do it only fire one time if it is below 768px and one time above 768px.

At first I didn't have my code inside the resize function, but then it would only work one time so that if I increased it about 768px, the header tag disappeared but if I decreased the size again the header didn't get reapplied.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 768) {
            insertHeader();
        }
        if(width > 767) {
            removeHeader();
        }
    });
});

//Function to add header
function insertHeader() {
    var headerTag = $("body").prepend(
                    "<header class='container container-style'> \
                        <div class='row'> \
                            <div class='col-xs-12'> \
                                <a href='#'><img class='img-responsive'  \
                                    src='img/dreamstime_s_52258696.jpg' alt='cartoon drawing of 1965 GTO'></a> \
                            </div>  \
                        </div> \
                    </header>");
    return headerTag
}

function removeHeader() {
    var headerTag = $("header").remove();
    return headerTag;   
}
```

Comment: Although the voted answer fix your problem it would take way less code to use CSS media queries as specified by @guest271314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css` media query

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/BsL71H91RVFgG3gUDexa?p=preview

Comment: Dang. That's a much better solution. I don't know why I didn't think about that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You just want to debounce the event, there's many ways to do this, but in this case a simple flag would suffice

```
$(window).data('flag', $(window).width() < 768).on('resize', function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var flag  = $(this).data('flag');

    if (width < 768 && flag) {
        insertHeader();
        $(this).data('flag', false);

    } else if (width > 768 && !flag) {
        removeHeader();
        $(this).data('flag', true);

    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/o5xpydn6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

check for header is in the DOM or not

```
if($('header').length < 1){

}
```

your code should looks like

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 768) {
          if($('header').length < 1){
             insertHeader();
          }

        }
        if(width > 767) {
           if($('header').length >= 1){
             removeHeader();
           }
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/wrkfmj28/)